# how to get the oldest person?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, max

I would like using a group by or any aggregation function, instead of this:

```
select birthday
from table
where birthday in ( select min(birthday) from table)
```

Comment: `MIN` *is* an aggregation function. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's wrong with your current query?

Comment: @Marco do you need all the people in case of same birthday or just one?

Comment: @vc74 i need to be shown all of them(with the same birthday)

Comment: @jarlh I would like to use aggregation functions.

Comment: As Giorgos Betsos already has said, MIN() is an aggregate function...

Comment: @jarlh i'd like to use group by

Comment: You don't need a group by here. I can't even figure out how it could be used in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you're not interested in just the birthday but also the other colums (otherwise `select min(birthday) from table` would work)

```
select *
from table
order by birthday
limit 1;
```

Should do it

Comment: this way, it'll show me just one occurence. If I have more than one with the same birthday, It shall show me all of them.

Comment: @Marco Hence my question in your original post ;)

Comment: @vc74 i replied to your question. Sorry, i've seen it right now

Answer (score 1):

In case someone comes here after 2.5 years - if you need only one person, vc 74's answer is a great one. In case you need all people who are the eldest, try this one:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    birthday = (SELECT max(birthday) FROM table);
```

or (using vc 74's answer):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    birthday = (SELECT birthday FROM table ORDER BY birthday DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all records with lower birthday date, you could try the following code:

```
select *
from table
having birthday = min(birthday)
```

Comment: Invalid query. A column in the HAVING clause must either be listed in GROUP BY, or be argument to an aggregate function.